# How does notch do collision detection in minicraft?

Tags: java, collision-detection

How does notch do collision in minicraft?

I am trying to find out how he does it for a game I am working on. In my game what I do is use rectangles and if they intersect with the other rectangles in the world, the x or y position pluses of minuses depending on which direction you were moving. Is this a good way of doing it?
If someone could please tell me how notch does collision in his game minicraft that would be great.

Thanks

Source Code of minicraft: https://s3.amazonaws.com/ld48/ld22/minicraft_source.zip

Comment: @NiklasB. note he's talking about `minicraft`, not minecraft. The source is included.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  (I am not about to click that link.)

Comment: It's not clear why you want to know how minicraft in particular does it. As far as your approach, if I understand you correctly you are using a kind of bounding box collision detection, which is common. Also see http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/collision-detection-r735 (google is your friend)

Comment: You can ask Notch himself, you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you describe is basically correct.

If you care about performance, be careful not to allocate any new objects during the collision checking, and remember you can speed things up by pre-calculating some stuff, i.e., a tree's `x + width` is always going to be the same.